# mapStateToProps called but components props not change?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have two containers `StatedUser` and  `StatedHeader`. which is connect with component `User` and `Header` They both recieve `state.user` as props. After some actions change `state.user`, component User `props.user` changes but Header not.

Here is my code  `container StatedHeader`

```
import Header from '../components/common/Header'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {showConfirm} from '../actions'

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(`header user --> ${JSON.stringify(state.user)}`)
  return {
    user: state.user,
    headerFix: state.headerFix       
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    openSignoutDialog: () => {
      dispatch(showConfirm(true))
    }
   }
 }

 const StatedHeader = connect(
   mapStateToProps,
   mapDispatchToProps)(Header)

 export default StatedHeader
```

------------------------------edit-------------------------------------

```
const  initialState = {
  user: {},
  displayFlag: false,
  headerFix: false
}

function blogApp (state, action) {
  if (typeof(state) === 'undefined') {
  return initialState
}

switch(action.type) {
  case 'SIGN_IN':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {user: action.user})
  // update user what i mentioned in the question
  case 'UPDATE_AVATAR':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {user: action.user})
  case 'SIGN_OUT':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {user: {}})
  case 'SHOW_CONFIRM':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {displayFlag: action.displayFlag})
  case 'HEADER_FIX':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {headerFix: action.headerFix})
  default: 
    return state
  }
}

export default blogApp
```

By the way, result of `console.log` found that `state.user`  did change as expected, but components' props didn't change.
By the way , my reac-redux version is **V5.0.5**
any ideas about it ? Thanks!

Comment: How are you accessing "user" prop in Header component?

Comment: @Dev , I just create a class  `Header` and use `this.props.user`, Listening at `componentWillReceiveProps ` which is never called after init.

Comment: I assume you might have used Header instead of StatedHeader as the container component, if not then I would need more to analyse the issue. As you are saying, you are receiving user data in mapStateToProps, it should update the Header component.

Comment: @Dev Thanks. I did use StatedHeader  as container. you can watch [here](https://github.com/cpprookie/reactblog) to get more message.

Comment: could you please share the code of the reducer that's updating the user? I think that the issue probably has to do with that.

Comment: @Josep sorry that i didn't response in time, I update the question. thank you.

Comment: @Dev i fixed the bug  and hope my answer could bring you something, thanks!

Comment: @Josep i fixed the bug  and hope my answer could bring you something, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After tracking the bug for a long time, i finally fix it.In `User.js` which tiggers the `UPDATE_AVATAR`.

```
axios.post(`/user/${this.state.author._id}/avatar`, formData)
  .then(res=> {
    this.setState({author: {avatar: res.data.avatar}})
    let user = this.props.user    //what should cause the bug.
    user.avatar = res.data.avatar
    this.props.changeAvatar(user)
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e.message))
```

What i'm doing here is  send a http request to post user's avatar and then trigger `changeAvatar` accessed by dispatch to update app's state.

In the debug process as following code jumping between breakpoints, i found that redux will check the object you passed to it.

In javascript, object is passed by reference with = operator.so i replace what i pointed in `User.js` with `user = Object.assign({}, this.props.user)` Then it works! Though i have no idea about the actual reason, but it did fix!